# iOS: Conditional code depending on current target

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I have two targets in my iPhone iOS project: `Production` and `Preview`.

I now want to execute a line of code, only if I am in the target `Preview`.
I guess this would have to be some sort of `#ifdef ...`. I found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657102/how-to-have-conditional-code-depending-on-active-configuration) which does almost the thing I want but it uses the *configuration* and not the *target*.

Example:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  #ifdef MY_PREVIEW_TARGET
    [SomeLibraryWhichIsInPreviewTarget someMethod];
  #endif

  // Code that applies for both targets ...
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could add a preprocessor ifdef in the Preprocessor Macros section of the build settings.

Comment: Why should it be Preprocessor macro. As its useful for "USER" it must be "User defined". Isn't it?

Comment: It's a pity that Xcode intellisense just breaks inside those conditional blocks of code.

Answer (score 39):

Sams solution worked fine.

1. Open The Preview's target's build settings
2. Set the `Preprocessor Macros` to `MY_PREVIEW_TARGET=YES` and then I can use my code above to check for the target.

Comment: Just add the entry `MY_PREVIEW_TARGET` to `Preprocessor Macros`. Then use `#ifdef MY_PREVIEW_TARGET` in your code. No need to actually set the macro to `YES` as in `MY_PREVIEW_TARGET=YES`. No need to set a value since you are not checking against that value, merely the existence of the variable.